# OSX Text to Speech, plus copy text, at the same time

Tags: macos

For the life of me I cannot make this work.

We are trying to get the text to be spoken and with the same press of the shortcut for text to speech, copy the text to the clipboard.

We have managed to get it to work from firefox, but it will not work with outlook and other programs, is there a way to do this with a script or something I am just entirely missing?

Thank you so much in advance.

Regards,

James